# Como modificar el constructor de una clase en su subclase

Tags: java, constructor

tengo un problema con una clase A que es heredada de una clase B.  en esta clase A necesito que un atributo heredado de esa clase B sea constante en su constructor.
intente con esto pero no me funciona.

```
public Fantasma(int ataque, int salud, int defensa, String descripcion) {
    super(ataque, salud, defensa, descripcion);
    this.setdescripsion(fantasma);
```

}

Comment: los métodos get generalmente no reciben nada por paramtros por eso la palabra get = obtener. Si quieres asignar una descripción deberías usar un método set, y luego  this.getdescripsion(); sin parametros.

Comment: hola @OscarPortillo disculpa me equivoque con get, como tu dices era el set. de todas formas me da una advertencia: overridable method call in constructor

Comment: Te responderé la pregunta en la  sección de respuesta.

Comment: ese fantasma deberia estar entre comillaas this.setdescripsion("fantasma");

Comment: @unknow no si lo tiene como variable al no tener el código completo no se sabe si fantasma es una variable con valor o existe el error que le comentas, pero es un buen aporte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Override Es la capacidad que tiene una clase que hereda de poder modificar los métodos de su clase padre, por ejemplo:

```
public class Persona{
  public String nombre;
  public void saludar()
   {
    System.out.println("Hola mundo");
   }
}
```

ahora sobreescribimos el método manejar, para que siga existiendo en la clase hija pero tenga distinto comportamiento

```
class Hijo extends Persona
{
     @Override
     public void saludar()
     {
        System.out.println("Saludando desde la clase Hijo que extiende de Persona");
     }
}
```

Ahora por ejemplo si quisieras acceder a los métodos de la clase sería:

```
public class MainClass {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Persona one = new Persona();  
      Persona two = new Hijo();  

      one.saludar();   
      two.saludar();  
   }
}
```

USO DE OVERRIDE.
En resumidas cuentas hacer override, permite a un método sobreescribir o modificar la declaración de un método en una clase superior.
Espero te sirva.